# Scala + SBT - How to configure reference.conf for a shaded Akka library

Tags: apache-spark, akka, cloudera-cdh, sbt-assembly, shading

## TL;DR

I am trying to shade a version of the `akka` library and bundle it with my application (to be able to run a `spray-can` server on the `CDH 5.7` version of `Spark 1.6`). The shading process [messes up `akka`'s default configuration](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/173), and after manually providing a separate version of `akka`'s `reference.conf` for the shaded `akka`, it still looks like the 2 versions get mixed up somehow.

Is shading `akka` versions known to cause problems? What am I doing wrong?

## Background

I have a `Scala`/`Spark` application currently running on `Spark 1.6.1` standalone. The application runs a [`spray-can`](http://spray.io/) http server using `spray 1.3.3`, which requires `akka 2.3.9` (`Spark 1.6.1` standalone includes a compatible `akka 2.3.11`).

I am trying to migrate the application to a new [`Cloudera`](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x.html)-based `Spark` cluster running the `CDH 5.7` version of `Spark 1.6`. The problem is that `Spark 1.6` in `CDH 5.7` is bundled with `akka 2.2.3` which is not sufficient for `spray 1.3.3` to function properly.

## Attempted solution

Following the suggestion in [this post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-1-6-1-on-CDH-5-7-0/td-p/45230), I decided to shade `akka 2.3.9` and bundle it along with my application. Although this time I stumbled upon a new problem - `akka` has it's default configuration defined in a `reference.conf` file, which should be located on the application's classpath. Due to a [known issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/173) in `sbt-assembly`'s shading feature, it seems that the shaded `akka` library would require a separate configuration.

So, I ended up shading `akka` with the following shade rule:

```
ShadeRule.rename("akka.**" -> "akka_2_3_9_shade.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.3.9")
    .inAll
```

and including an additional `reference.conf` file in my project, which is identical to `akka`'s original `reference.conf`, but with all occurances of "akka" replaced with "akka_2_3_9_shade".

Now, though, it seems that the `Spark`-provided `akka` gets mixed up somehow with the shaded `akka`, as I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate MailboxType [akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox], defined in [akka.actor.default-mailbox], make sure it has a public constructor with [akka.actor.ActorSystem.Settings, com.typesafe.config.Config] parameters
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.dispatch.Mailboxes$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Mailboxes.scala:197)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.dispatch.Mailboxes$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Mailboxes.scala:195)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.dispatch.Mailboxes.lookupConfiguration(Mailboxes.scala:195)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.dispatch.Mailboxes.lookup(Mailboxes.scala:78)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.akka$actor$LocalActorRefProvider$$defaultMailbox$lzycompute(ActorRefProvider.scala:561)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.akka$actor$LocalActorRefProvider$$defaultMailbox(ActorRefProvider.scala:561)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.LocalActorRefProvider$$anon$1.<init>(ActorRefProvider.scala:568)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.rootGuardian$lzycompute(ActorRefProvider.scala:564)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.rootGuardian(ActorRefProvider.scala:563)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.init(ActorRefProvider.scala:618)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:619)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:616)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:616)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:633)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:100)
    at MyApp.api.Boot$delayedInit$body.apply(Boot.scala:45)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at MyApp.api.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:28)
    at MyApp.api.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: interface akka_2_3_9_shade.dispatch.MailboxType is not assignable from class akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:69)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at akka_2_3_9_shade.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.CreateInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    ... 34 more
```

The relevant code from my application's `Boot.scala` file is the following:

```
[45]    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
...
[48]    val service = system.actorOf(Props[MyAppApiActor], "MyApp.Api")
...
[52]    val port = config.getInt("MyApp.server.port")
[53]    IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, interface = "0.0.0.0", port = port)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so eventually I managed to solve this.

Turns out `akka` loads (some of the) configuration settings from the config file using keys that are defined as string literals. You can find a lot of these in [`akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala#L178), for example.

And it seems that `sbt-assembly` **does not** change references to the shaded library/package name in string literals.

Also, some configuration keys **are** being changed by `sbt-assembly`'s shading. I haven't really taken the time to find where and how exactly they are defined in `akka`'s source, but the following exception, which is being thrown during the `ActorSystem` init code, proves that this is indeed the case:

```
ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka_2_3_9_shade'
```

So, the solution it to include a custom config file (call it for example `akka_spray_shade.conf`), and copy the following configuration sections in it:

- The contents of `akka`'s original `reference.conf`, but having the `akka` prefix in the configuration values changed to `akka_2_3_9_shade`. (this is required for the hard-coded string literal config keys)
- The contents of `akka`'s original `reference.conf`, but having the `akka` prefix in the configuration values changed to `akka_2_3_9_shade` **and having the root configuration key changed** from `akka` to `akka_2_3_9_shade`. (this is required for the config keys which do get modified by `sbt-assembly`)
- The contents of `spray`'s original `reference.conf`, but having the `akka` prefix in the configuration values changed to `akka_2_3_9_shade`. (this is required to make sure that `spray` always refers to the shaded `akka`)

Now, this custom config file must be provided **explicitly** during the initialization of the `ActorSystem` in application's `Boot.scala` code:

```
val akkaShadeConfig = ConfigFactory.load("akka_spray_shade")
implicit val system = ActorSystem("custom-actor-system-name", akkaShadeConfig)
```

Comment: This hack works, but good luck if the akka keys change or even if you introduce your own akka settings. The proper solution would be to also "shade" the configuration keys programmatically. `sbt-assembly` doesn't seem to provide such a functionality yet; perhaps it's possible to do oneself via sbt.

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to the accepted answer.

It is not necessary to put this configuration in a custom-named file like `akka_spray_shade.conf`. The configuration can be placed into `application.conf` which is being loaded by default during `ActorSystem` creation when no custom configuration is explicitly specified: `ActorSystem("custom-actor-system-name")` effectively means `ActorSystem("custom-actor-system-name", ConfigFactory.load("application"))`.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a long time as well. It turns out that the default merge strategy in `sbt-assembly` excludes all the `reference.conf` files. Adding this to `build.sbt` solved it for me:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
}
```